# Does posting a review on Steam give me better recommendations?

Tags: steam

I know that Steam harvests all kinds of interesting data points to determine what games to recommend; for example, it recommended a 2D shooter roguelike to me "because you spent 0.1 hours playing Enter the Gungeon."

If I leave recommendations (good or bad) for games I own, does that give Steam more data and result in better recommendations?

Comment: There's [a meta post here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12616/would-a-question-asking-about-how-steams-recommendations-feature-works-on-top) about whether these types of questions are on-topic or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no actual source for that other than Steam *not* mentioning it, but I'm certain that your reviews/recs have no impact on your own recommendations.

[Steam itself](http://store.steampowered.com/recommended/) says (when you're not logged in) your recommendations are influenced by

- what your friends are playing and what they have reviewed.
- games similar to what you've been playing. (your case)
- new content available for games you own.

I believe it would be impractical and falsify the results, if Steam would actually take your own reviews into account for your recs. The reviews you post are for one single game and granted that you own that one game already a new recommendation would make no sense. Also a review is for a single game, not for the genre of it. Only because you like or dislike that one game it would have little to no impact on the rest of the genre and you would probably still (not) play it.

Posting reviews still has a positive result, since they have an impact on the recs to your friends and games you hate are less likely recommended to them.

PS: While it may be possible to get less recommendations for additional content for games you've given a bad rating it's still possible, because this happened to me. So it's safe to assume that even there your own recs are not (or very little) influenced by your reviews. It's more helpful to not play those games than giving a bad review.

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems really strange to me that what your friends reviewed influences your queues, but your own bad reviews don't influence queues (and instead, Steam says "oh you played that game, here's a similar one.")

Comment: @ashes999 it sounds stranger than it is. There are people who like shooters and dislike a specific game like CS Source (or the old CS 1.6 vs CSS rage wars, FIFA vs PES, etc). They could give CSS a bad rating and would still love to hear about and try other shooters or even CS GO.

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks for taking the time out to research this and explain it so clearly.